# ElasticSearch: how is the score for nested queries computed?

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

Ho is the score for nested query computed?
I have the case with:

```
{
  "name": "Lukas",
  "works": {
    "title": "developer",
    "current": true,
    "dummy": "match"
  }
}
```

No nested fields.
And a different type of index with these fields as nested and as array.:

```
{
  "name": "Lukas",
  "works": [
    {
      "title": "developer",
      "current": true,
      "dummy": "match"
    },
    {
      "title": "dad",
      "current": true
    }
  ]
}
```

If I make the same `query_search` against the 2 indexes (for an existing word), the score is dramatically different.
How is the score computed for nested queries?

(Explanation received with `explain:true`:

```
{
  "_explanation": {
    "value": 0.68874943,
    "description": "Score based on child doc range from 0 to 3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [Explain API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html)? Does it give you any insights?

Comment: I did someting else: I put in the query body 'explain:true', but it is extremely poor in explanations.

Comment: Perhaps you could share the results of the explain, it could help us understand more about this.

Comment: Well, that isn't very innformative. The Explain API is supposed to give a better breakup, and help find out what factors are contributing to the score.

Answer (score 0):

Each shard has its own TF and IDF and this could be contributing to the different scores:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/FK-PYb43zcQ

Also, the number of documents in an index with nested documents contains all of the nested documents. For example consider a smaller mapping with "works->title" only. With 3 candidates having 1, 3 and 5 titles there will be 12 documents. I believe these come from the 3 root documents and the (1+3+5 = 9) nested documents. This is likely to produce a very different IDF.

This assumes that your mapping specifies nested and your query is of nested type.